# Pairing rows in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table similar to the one obtained with the following command:

```
dt <- data.table(
  time = 1:8,
  part = rep(c(1, 1, 2, 2), 2),
  type = rep(c('A', 'B'), 4),
  data = rep(c(runif(1), 0), 4))
```

Basically, such a table contains two different type of instances (A or B). The time column contains a timestamp for when a request arrived to or leaved from a certain part. If the instance type is A, the timestamp states the arrival time (enter), and if the type is B, the timestamp states the leaving time (exit).

```
   time part type      data
1:    1    1    A 0.5842668
2:    2    1    B 0.0000000
3:    3    2    A 0.5842668
4:    4    2    B 0.0000000
5:    5    1    A 0.5842668
6:    6    1    B 0.0000000
7:    7    2    A 0.5842668
8:    8    2    B 0.0000000
```

I would like to pair A and B instances, and obtain the following data table:

```
   part data        enter.time exit.time
1:    1 0.4658239   1          2
2:    1 0.4658239   5          6
3:    2 0.4658239   3          4
4:    2 0.4658239   7          8
```

I have tried the following:

```
pair.types <- function(x) {
  a.type <- x[type == 'A']
  b.type <- x[type == 'B']
  return(data.table(
      enter.time = a.type$time,
      exit.time = b.type$time,
      data = a.type$data))
}

dt[, c('enter.time', 'exit.time', 'data') := pair.types(.SD), by = list(part)]
```

But, that gives me the following, which is not exactly what I want:

```
   time part type      data enter.time exit.time
1:    1    1    A 0.3441592          1         2
2:    2    1    B 0.3441592          5         6
3:    3    2    A 0.3441592          3         4
4:    4    2    B 0.3441592          7         8
5:    5    1    A 0.3441592          1         2
6:    6    1    B 0.3441592          5         6
7:    7    2    A 0.3441592          3         4
8:    8    2    B 0.3441592          7         8
```

It is kind of close, but since column 'type' is kept, some rows are duplicated. Perhaps, I can try to remove columns 'time' and 'type', and then remove the second half of rows. But, I am not sure whether that will work in all the cases, and I would like to learn a better way to do this operation.

Comment: Are your paired rows always one after the other? That is, first `A` and then the corresponding `B`

Comment: @JuliánUrbano Yes, corresponding A-B pairs are always consecutive. At least, that has been the case in the data that I have observed so far. If it is not too much difficult, though, I would be interested in a general solution.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data looks like your example data:

```
dt[, list(part = part[1],
          data = data[1],
          enter.time = time[1],
          exit.time = time[2]),
     by = as.integer((seq_len(nrow(dt)) + 1)/2)]
#    by = rep(seq(1, nrow(dt), 2), each = 2)]
#    ^^^ a slightly shorter and a little more readable alternative
```

The idea is very simple - group rows in groups of 2 (that's the `by` part), i.e. each group will be one A and one B, then for each group take first `part` and first `data` and then the enter and exit times are just the first and second `time`'s respectively. This is likely how you'd do this if you followed the by-hand logic, making it easy to read (once you know just a tiny bit about how `data.table` works).

Comment: can you explain *how* this solution works? I want to upvote you because this seems really elegant, and the *right* answer but I don't feel it is useful to a wider audience without some explanations! Thanks :-)

Comment: I also have a nagging suspicion that the by part could be simplified a lot.

Comment: (+1) eddi, how about? `dt[, as.list(c(data=data[1], entry=time[1], exit=time[2])), by = list(part, rep(1:4, each=2))]`

Comment: +1 thanks, your explanation helped me understand perfectly what you implemented. Great solution!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is really interesting to see data.table in action. Unfortunately, when creating a toy example for posting it here, I oversimplified the problem. Shall I update the question, or is it better to create a new one?

Comment: @betabandido either option is ok by me; @Arun, not really sure why you included the `part` in your list, and I guess 4 is too specific, but yeah, smth along those lines, e.g. `rep(seq(1, nrow(dt), 2), each = 2)` works - I'm guessing this is slightly easier to read

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
setkey(dt, "type")
dt.out <- cbind(dt[J("A"), list(part, data, entry.time = time)][, type := NULL], 
      exit.time = dt[J("B"), list(time)]$time)
#    part      data entry.time exit.time
# 1:    1 0.1294204          1         2
# 2:    2 0.1294204          3         4
# 3:    1 0.1294204          5         6
# 4:    2 0.1294204          7         8
```

If you want you can now do `setkey(dt.out, "part")` to get the same order.

---

The idea: Your problem seems a simple "reshaping" one to me. The way I've approached it is first to create a key column as `type`. Now, we can subset data.table for a specific value in the key column by: `dt[J("A")]`. This would return the entire `data.table`. Since you want the column `time` renamed, I explicitly mention which columns to subset using:

```
dt[J("A"), list(part, data, entry.time = time)]
```

Of course this'll return also the `type` column (= A) which we've to remove. So, I've added a `[, type := NULL]` to remove column `type` by reference.

Now we've the first part. All we need is the `exit.time`. This can be obtained similarly as:

```
dt[J("B"), list(time)] # I don't name the column here
```

But this gives a `data.table` when you need just the time column, which can be accessed by:

```
dt[J("B"), list(time)]$time
```

So, while using `cbind` I name this column as `exit.time` to get the final result as:

```
cbind(dt[J("A"), list(part, data, entry.time = time)][, type := NULL], 
      exit.time = dt[J("B"), list(time)]$time)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Arun same to you (see comment under eddi 's solution) - please can you explain for us `data.table` novices *how* this works?!

Comment: I usually write `The idea:` and explain. But I am still working on the answer :).

Comment: lol!!! Yes ok, I often do this too - you have to be quick on here! Especially with sexy topics like `data.table` :-)

Comment: @SimonO101, no, you're totally right. Sometimes I forget to explain. It makes more sense to make that effort so that it's useful for a wider audience. I'll remember this for my  future answers.

Comment: Ah, yes, data.table syntax! So simple, compact, intuitive and easy to read! ;)

Comment: @joran, are you waiting for dplyr :)

Comment: :) probably my explanation takes people further away from `data.table` rather than welcoming. I should stop with "the idea".

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is really interesting to see data.table in action. Unfortunately, when creating a toy example for posting it here, I oversimplified the problem. Shall I update the question, or is it better to create a new one?